# How to set tag of UIbutton with 2 dimensional array

Tags: iphone

I want to set tag of UIbutton with 2 dimensional array ->

Here my code, don't know where I am wrong.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<[arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode count] ; i++)
{           
    btnLandscape_Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnLandscape_Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btnLandscape_Button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,50);
    [btnLandscape_Button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    btnLandscape_Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [arrCommonDays[1][i] addObject:[arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i]];
    [btnLandscape_Button setTag:[1][arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i]];
    [btnLandscape_Button addTarget:self    action:@selector(btnClick_ForDetailInformation_For_Class_InLandscapeMode:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnLandscape_Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [viewForDisplayData_OnDaily addSubview:btnLandscape_Button];

            [btnLandscape_Button setTitle:[dictWeeklyData_InLandscape_Mode objectForKey:@"sSubjectCode"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```

Comment: If you want to create a grid view then i can help to create this and add tag and access each button and can change the image of each button when you like to

Comment: thanks for replying . can you help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that your arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode array is a 2 dimensional one (array of arrays) then you should extract values from it the next way:

```
[btnLandscape_Button setTag:[[arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

or

```
[btnLandscape_Button setTag:[[arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i]];
```

as for your needs.

Comment: Thanks For Replying First but this answer didn't help me out. 
arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode array is a one dimensional and [arrCommonDays[1][i] is a two dimensional array. Value of i is coming from [arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i]] and arrCommonDays[1][i], 1 is static for this loop and for next loop I have taken arrCommonDays[2][i], in this case value of i is coming from [arrtemp objectAtIndex:i] I am creating button for each loop and want to set tag for the same. [btnLandscape_Button setTag:[1][arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i]] Thanks

Comment: What does this code means setTag:[1][arrWeekly_Fetch_DataForLandscapeMode objectAtIndex:i] ??? I mean the "[1]" ??? I have never seen such a construction.